How to transfer method to Next in JQUERY Form
This is my script, I want to send a method to next Button in step form when user want to go from form 3 to form 4:
(function ($) {
    "use strict"

    var form = $("#step-form-horizontal");
    form.children('div').steps({
        headerTag: "h4",
        bodyTag: "section",
        transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
        autoFocus: true,
        onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex) {
            // Check if the user is moving to the second step
            if (newIndex === 1) {
                // Scroll to the top of the page
                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
            }
            // Validate the form on each step change
            form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";
            return form.valid();
        }
    });

    var form2 = $("#step-form-tab");
    form2.children('div').steps({
        headerTag: "h4",
        bodyTag: "section",
        enableFinishButton: false,
        enablePagination: false,
        enableAllSteps: true,
        titleTemplate: "#title#"
    });

    var form3 = $('#step-form-vertical');
    form3.children('div').steps({
        headerTag: "h4",
        bodyTag: "section",
        transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
        stepsOrientation: "vertical"
    });

})(jQuery);



I want when click on next in form from form 3to 4 , in same time execuet this method in C# in ASP.NET
     [HttpPost]
     public IActionResult SaveDeliveryAndPaymentDetails(CartViewModel model)
     {
         if (model != null && model.CartDeliveryDateViewModel != null)
         {
             var deliveryAndPaymentDetails = new CartDeliveryAndPaymentDetails
             {
                 DeliveryDate = model.CartDeliveryDateViewModel.DeliveryDate,
                 DeliveryTime = model.CartDeliveryDateViewModel.DeliveryTime,
                 Details = model.CartDeliveryDateViewModel.Details,
                 PaymentMethod = model.CartDeliveryDateViewModel.PaymentMethod
             };

             _orderService.SaveDeliveryAndPaymentDetailsInSession(deliveryAndPaymentDetails);

             // Redirect to the checkout page to show form 4
             return RedirectToAction("CheckOut");
         }
         else
         {
             // Handle the case where model or its properties are null
             return RedirectToAction("Index"); // Or any other appropriate action
         }
     }

so I want pass next buttom form 3 to form 4 to this method. how can I do ?
SaveDeliveryAndPaymentDetails

and this is my buttom:
    <div class="header">
        <button id="prevBtn">&lt;</button>
        <h2 id="monthYear">Month Year</h2>
        <button id="nextBtn">&gt;</button>
    </div>

